# How to run 2 python scripts at sime time over ethernet?

Tags: python, embedded, controls, ethernet

I have 2 py scripts that are sending commands via ethernet to turn on/off logic levels in various electronic components. The GUI's themselves are a very simple interface, however, I am not a python guy. I am able to open up one GUI with Spyder, run the script and control the system just fine, but I need to run 2 scripts simultaneously. Both scripts are similar in nature and operation. Is there a way to run both in Spyder? Or one from two different IDE's? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i fully understand your use case but if the scripts don't take long to execute and when you say run simultaneously you mean at very nearly the same time then you could just write a shell script to execute them consecutively with some timer function if running on a regular schedule. Might need more details to know if that's appropriate. If you need them to run in parallel then that's a different matter.

You'll just be creating a file.sh with something along the lines of:

```
python script1.py
python script2.py
```

inside and some logic to run it on whatever schedule you desire

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need them to run in parallel. I do not have the ability to alter the code. These are 2 scripts that were provided to me and I would like to run them both in parallel. At this point the only solution is using two computers but I would like to run them both on one.

Answer (score 0):

Do they have to run in Spyder?  If they are just python scripts you should not need an IDE, just use two command line terminals and run `script1.py` in one, and `script2.py` in the other

Comment: That's actually what I did and now the GUI's both at least open up. I haven't got to a point yet that I can test both of them but will soon. Thank you.